# "content://sms" not working in android 2.3.x OS version

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I am trying to read all SMS from android device using following content provider:

```
content://sms
```

in this way:

```
context.getContentResolver().query("content://sms", null, null,null, "date DESC")
```

but the cursor return null in android OS version 2.3.3.
But same code work fine in android 2.2 and 4.0.

I don't understand what is problem, may be "content://sms" content provider not supported by Android 2.3.3 OS version, if yes then please tell me what is the corrrect way to find content provider for SMS.

Comment: There may not be a "content provider for SMS" on any given device. Even if it exists on a device, it may not be used by the user's chosen SMS client on a device.